# a cardinality inequality

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

Denote $E=\{1,2,...,n\}$ for some positive integer $n\geq 2$. Denote
\begin{equation*}
E_k=\{\Omega\subset E||\Omega|=k\},\quad k=1,2,...,n.
\end{equation*}
Here, $|\cdot|$ denotes a cardinality of a set.
Let $S_k\subset E_k$ for $k=1,2,...,n$. Suppose that for any $\Omega\in S_k$ with $k<n$ and for any $i\in E\setminus \Omega$, it holds $$(\Omega\cup\{i\})\in S_{k+1}.$$

I guess $\frac{|S_k|}{|E_k|}\leq\frac{|S_{k+1}|}{|E_{k+1}|}$ for any $k<n$? Is my proposition correct? Can anyone help me prove it or give some counter example?

Comment: Can you show us why you think this holds, please?

Comment: Because in the research area of "exact matrix completion", people claim this equality is obvious. They claim that matrix completion problem with more constraints are more likely to recovery in probability sense. My proposition is just a mathematical interpretation of their claim.

Comment: Let me try to parse and understand your notation... so $E$ is a finite set with $n$ elements and $E_k$ is the set of all subsets of $E$ which have $k$ elements?  We have notation for that.  We would normally have written this as $\binom{E}{k}$ and you should note that $|\binom{E}{k}|=\binom{|E|}{k}=\binom{n}{k}$, the binomial coefficient.  Now... I'm trying to understand how $S_k$ fits into this.  $S_k$ you say is just some subset of $E_k$, but which subset of $E_k$?  There are several.  And $S_{k+1}$?  Are we picking just any two $S_k$ and $S_{k+1}$ such that your extra conditions hold?

Comment: Yes, exactly, any two $S_k$ and $S_{k+1}$ satisfying the extra condition. And $E_k$ is the set of all subsets of $E$ which have $k$ elements?

Comment: Out of each $\Omega \in S_k$, one can build $n-k$ elements of $S_{k+1}$ by adjunction of some $i\in E \setminus \Omega$.
One hence gets $|S_{k+1}| \geqslant (n-k)|S_k| - |S_k| =  (n-k-1)|S_k|$

Comment: But these $(n-k)|S_k|$ elements may duplicate

Comment: @LinXuelei Correct, they may duplicate, but you'll get at most $|S_k|$ duplicates, whence the "$-|S_k|$ " part on the right hand side.

Comment: @JMoravitz in my reply to JMoravitz, there is a inappropriate question mark. Let me correct my reply. Yes, exactly, any two $S_k$ and $S_{k+1}$ satisfying the extra condition. And $E_k$ is the set of all subsets of $E$ which have $k$ elements.

Comment: @LinXuelei I can't understand your counterexample...

Comment: @Olivier Roche sorry, it not a counterexample, I have deleted it. But can you prove your inequality?

Comment: If you take $S_k=E_k$, the sequence of $(|S_k|)$ will be decreasing after $n/2$, so this inequality doesn't hold @OlivierRoche

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result follows from a modification of a comment by @OlivierRoche

Out of each $\Omega \in S_k$ we can build $n-k$ elements of $S_{k+1}$ by adjuncting some $i \in E \setminus \Omega$.

Let us be more explicit.  Consider all triplets of the form $(\Omega, i, \Omega \cup \{i\})$ where $\Omega \in S_k, i \in E \setminus \Omega$.

The number of such triplets $= |S_k| (n - k)$, because for every $\Omega \in S_k$ we can choose $i$ in $(n-k)$ different ways.

In each such triplet, the last member $(\Omega \cup \{i\}) \in S_{k+1}$ by the given property in the OP.

Now, consider some $\Lambda \in S_{k+1}$.  In how many triplets can $\Lambda$ appear (as the last member, obviously)?  I claim that $\Lambda$ can appear in at most $k+1$ such triplets.  This is because the $i$ in the triplet must be $\in \Lambda$, and there are only $k+1$ such choices for $i$.  (This is what I meant when I originally said "$\Lambda$ can only be built from some $\Omega$ in at most $k+1$ different ways.")

Let $N(\Lambda)$ be the number of times $\Lambda$ appears in these triplets, i.e. the no. of ways to build $\Lambda$ using some $\Omega \in S_k$.  Thus we have $N(\Lambda) \le k+1$.

Summing over all $\Lambda \in S_{k+1}$ we have:

$$\sum_{\Lambda \in S_{k+1}} N(\Lambda) = \text{no. of triplets} = |S_k| (n-k)$$

Note that the summation only needs to cover $\Lambda \in S_{k+1}$, because only such $\Lambda$ can appear as the third member in these triplets, by the given property of the OP.  I.e., we do not need to include any $\Lambda' \in E_{k+1} \setminus S_{k+1}$ because such $\Lambda'$ cannot appear in these triplets (i.e. cannot be built from some $\Omega \in S_k$).

Meanwhile, based on $N(\Lambda) \le k+1$ we also have:

$$\sum_{\Lambda \in S_{k+1}} N(\Lambda) \le \sum_{\Lambda \in S_{k+1}} (k+1) = |S_{k+1}| (k+1)$$

$$|S_{k+1}| \ge {n-k \over k+1} |S_k|$$

The result now easily follows from $|E_k| = {n \choose k}$ by expanding into factorials:

$${|E_{k+1}| \over |E_k|} = {{n \choose k+1} \over {n \choose k}} = {n! \over (k+1)! (n-k-1)!}{k! (n-k)! \over n!} = {n-k \over k+1} \le {|S_{k+1}| \over |S_k|}$$

Comment: Of course.  You misunderstood me.  I'm saying $\Lambda$ *can be built from* $\Omega \cup \{x\}$ iff $\Omega = \Lambda \setminus \{x\} \in S_{k}$.  Since there are only $k+1$ different $x \in \Lambda$, so $\Lambda$ can be built this way in $k+1$ different ways _or less_.  ...  Would it be helpful if I write it out explicitly in terms of triplets $(\Omega, x, \Lambda)$ and count them two ways?

Comment: Okay, I admit that I misunderstand the point. So, the comment is deleted. But I don't understand where does $|S_{k+1}|\geq \frac{n-k}{k+1}|S_{k}|$ come from. Even if for distinct $\Lambda$ and $\tilde{\Lambda}$, $\Lambda\setminus\{x\}$ and $\tilde{\Lambda}\setminus\{\tilde{x}\}$ may be identical. It would be very helpful, if you could show more details of your argument.

Comment: hope the new edits help? sorry if i was not clear originally. pls lemme know whether you still have questions.

Comment: Thanks. I've check it. I can not find anything wrong.